# Cómo puedo pintar de un color la columna con mayor valor en asp.net mvc 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Buena tardes amigos
Me gustaría saber cómo puedo  pintar de un color la columna con mayor valor, como se visualiza en la imagen de abajo
Estoy utilizando ASP .NET MVC 5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos Enmnuel, por curiosidad hermano, ¿Qué has intentado? Te invito a dar un recorrido por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que conozcas el funcionamiento adecuado, así aumentas las chances de obtener respuestas :D

Comment: Podrás [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código que utilizas para llenar tu tabla. La manera como propones tu respuesta no esta clara.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar if en la vista:

```
<td class="@if (Model > 5) { <text>bg-success</text> } ">
```

Para introducir tu clase como texto, no olvides poner el tag < text>